# Rearranging terms in a series

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am considering the limit of the sum S of an alternating series $p_1,n_1, p_2,n_2, p_3,n_3…$ where $p_n$ are positive and $n_n$ negative terms. If the limit exist = P of the sum of the positive terms and N = the limit of the sum of the negative terms, I assume that S=P+N.
I now assume that rearranging will not change the limit of the sum of the original series.

I reason intuitively: A large amount of positive terms occurring first would bring the partial sum close to S. Sooner or later however, the first negative term $n_1 $ would appear and bring the sum below $S-n_1 $. This holds for whatever additional amount of positive terms added. Repeating the procedure by adding $n_2$ and $n_3$ etc. brings the sum close to P+N = S. The same would hold if the negative terms were simultaneously rearranged, indicating that rearrangement of this type of series would have no impact on the summation.

Is this right?

Comment: This is only true for absolutely convergent series. Series that are not absolutely convergent are called conditionally convergent (which may seem a bit strange, but this is because you cannot rearrange the terms into any sequence consisting of the same terms). An example of a conditionally convergent series is $\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{5}, ...$

Comment: Is my series not absolutely convergent having a limit for both the sums of the positive and the negative terms?

Comment: Not as long as it contains negative terms $n_k$, no. An absolutely convergent series consists of only positive terms $p_n$. So, to start investigating what happens with alternating signs of any permulation order, you need the assumption that your original series is absolutely convergent, first.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis "An absolutely convergent series consists of only positive terms" ?? What about say $\sum (-1)^k/k^2$ for example?

Comment: @MikaelJensen In my opinion you are correct. (see my answer below)

Comment: @coffeemath Er, yes. Sorry. I meant if it converges AS an absolutely convergent series. Not that the OP's series IS absolutely convergent or yours contains only positive terms.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis The distinction should be drawn: absolutely convergent means only that the series of (positive) absolute values converges. The OP's assumptions imply absolute convergence because each of the individual series P,N are seen to be absolutely convergent, provided they each converge. [It's important that OP assumed each of P,N converges for this conclusion.]

Comment: @coffeemath: I agree wholeheartedly. Upon the extensive re-editing of the question, the separate convergence of the P and N partials sums is enough to keep me quiet. (If I recall well, this assumption wasn't there when I commented, but I may be mistaken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already assumed the individual series of p's and n's are convergent, then each of the individual sums for P and for N are absolutely convergent already. For P each term is already positive, so the sum of absolutes is just the sum of the p's. And for the other series N each term n is negative, so that the absolute values of the n terms are "all in the same direction", and the sum N (which is negative) is the same as the negative of the sum of absolute n's because of $ |n_k|=-n_k.$

So given your assumptions that each of the P and N sums converge to begin with, the whole series is absolutely convergent.

Note that of course this doesn't apply to rearranging the convergent $1-1/2+1/3-1/4...$ because in your notation neither of $P=1+1/3+1/5...$ or $N=(-1/2)+(-1/4)+...$ is convergent, making this example not fit your assumptions.

ADDED -- To spell it out a bit more, you have assumed $\sum p_k$ converges, say to some finite positive number $x$. And you have also assumed $\sum n_k$ converges, say to some negative number $y$. Since for each $k$ we have $p_k \ge 0$ and for each $k$ we have $n_k \le 0$ we have $\sum |p_k|=\sum p_k =x,$ and also $$\sum |n_k|=\sum (-1)n_k=(-1)\sum n_k=-y.$$
So the sum of absolute values of the whole interlaced sequence is $x-y.$ [Note this is nonnegative since $x \ge 0,\ y \le 0.$]